# Replacing a file in an Anaconda directory with a file in a different Anaconda directory, from the Anaconda prompt

Tags: anaconda

Apologies in advance if I shouldn't be posting here.  I was directed here by regular stack overflow.

I'm not that computer literate, although I'm old enough to somewhat remember navigating DOS on an IBM in the late 80's, and this seems similar.

I'm trying to get graphviz to work with jupyter notebook so that I can print a visualization of a decision tree for a class I'm taking.  I have jupyter notebook code from the instructor that should work.  However, I'm getting an installation error.

I've done some research and found out that the 'fix' requires me to open an Anaconda prompt and install a pipeline or something like that.  Unfortunately, I get a Windows error.  I researched the particular error and found a github discussion thread that's on point for this Windows error.

There's consensus that one of the posts in the thread works.  It says:

***I had the same issue.
I found out libssl-1_1-x64 dlls in Anaconda/DLLS and Anaconda/Library/bin being installed at different dates, so, as an experiment, I copied the one in Anaconda/DLLS and replaced that in Anaconda/Library/bin and conda started working again, at least for now - I could install new packages again.***

My understanding is that:

'libssl-1_1-x64 dlls' is the name of a file within two anaconda directories;

I need to first delete it in the 'Anaconda/Library/bin';

Copy the version of that file, located in 'Anaconda/DLLS';

Paste that copy in 'Anaconda/Library/bin'

So my question is, what are the exact commands I need to enter into my Anaconda prompt to accomplish this?  And is there anything else I need to do?

Once this is done, I believe I have the Anaconda commands that will successfully install (pipeline?...is that the term?), or otherwise make available for import in jupyter notebook, graphviz.

TIA for any help.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to first delete it in the 'Anaconda/Library/bin'.

It would likely be better to rename the file instead.

> So my question is, what are the exact commands I need to enter into my Anaconda prompt to accomplish this?

You would likely want to use a normal command or file explorer window to accomplish this task, not an Anaconda prompt.

> And is there anything else I need to do?

Closing Anaconda, moving the DLL, and then restarting Anaconda seems likely to be the steps you need to take (so Anaconda isn't using the DLL when you are attempting to move it and it can reload the new DLL once it is restarted).

**General Steps**

1. Close Anaconda.
2. Open a normal file explorer window and enter the full path to Anaconda into your address bar. If you don't know where you installed Anaconda, you will need to figure that out (it may be under a Windows `Program Files` folder or one of the folders in `AppData` for your Windows user name).
3. Once in e.g. `C:\path\to\Anaconda` look for the `Library` folder. Open it by clicking it and then do the same thing with the `bin` folder in the `Library` directory.
4. Once in the `bin` folder, look for the proper DLL (e.g. `libssl-1_1-x64.dll`). Right click the file and `Rename` it (including the extension) to something like e.g. `libssl-1_1-x64.dll.original`.
5. Repeat Step 3, except navigate to your `DLLS` directory under `Anaconda` (so back out of the `bin` and `Library` folders).
6. Once in the `DLL` folder, look for the proper DLL (e.g. `libssl-1_1-x64.dll`). Right click the file and `Copy` it.
7. Repeat Step 3 to return to your `bin` folder.
8. Find some white space and right-click it. Then `Paste` the DLL you copied in Step 6 into the folder.
9. Start Anaconda.
10. Profit ???